# Heroku Applications within AWS VPC

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, vpc

I have a small Rails app which I'm keen to deploy through Heroku (as I do with other clients) however this is not intended to be a publicly available application and they need to deploy it within their AWS VPC as if it is accessible within their internal network.

Is this something which is possible? I know that Heroku is built on top of EC2 but wasn't sure quite how flexible it was and haven't been able to find anything documented.

If not possible would anyone be able to offer experiences of pre-built Rails AMIs that I might be able to use in order to replicate some for the Heroku deployment simplicity without having to worry too much about configuring and managing my own infrastructure for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [git-deploy](https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy) might be what you need for git-style deployment.

I also found [quite an interesting blog post by Giles Bowkett](http://gilesbowkett.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/heroku-style-deployment-on-ec2.html) that might be interesting to you.